# question about the transformation of a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a question about Markov Process:

Let $X_t=(X_t^1, X_t^2,..., X_t^n)$ be a Markov process with regard to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, let $Y_t:=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}X_t^k$, then is $Y_t$ a Markov process with respect to the filtration $\sigma(Y_s, s\leq t)$?

I believe the answer is no, but could someone give me a counterexample? Many thanks!

Comment: I think, that would be easy to show even in case $n=2$ and two Continuous-time Markov chains, each say taking two values $0,1,2$ and $-1,1,3$. Then if the current value of the maximum is $1$, you don't know on which of the chains it is achieved, so you don't know what's the probability of the next jumps. It is worth, of course, elaborating formally on such example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is that we ask whether $Y_t$ is a MP w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_t^Y:=\sigma(Y_s, s\leq t)$ but not $\mathcal{F}_t$. I have tried with an example like this, but I did not find the counterexample. I find always an example like the Bronian motion $W_t$, then $|W_t|$ is also a MP. Could you give a precise example? Thanks a lot

Comment: Of course, I got the filtration you mean. I'll try to find a slot to work out an example, but *It's gonna take patience and time to do it* Can you tell me, what is unclear in the hint I suggested? That would be faster

Answer (score 0):

Consider two independent standard random walks in continuous time $(X^1_t)$ and $(X^2_t)$. Then $Y_t=\max(X^1_t,X^2_t)$ jumps from $Y_t=y$ to $y+1$ at rate $2$ if $X^1_t=X^2_t$ and to $y+1$ or to $y-1$, both at rate $1$, otherwise. The trouble is that the event $[X^1_t=X^2_t]$ is not in $\sigma(Y_s,s\leqslant t)$.